# UITableViewCell custom view in the top

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to add custom `UIView` for example with 10px of height to the top of my `UITableviewCell`.

My `UITableview` is grouped style and the problem is that my `UIView` is not rounded and `UITableviewCell` does not clip this view.

Here is the code of `awakeFromNib` for `CustomCell`

```
-(void) awakeFromNib
{
    self.clipsToBounds=YES;
    self.headerView.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
}
```

Here is the final result which i want to achieve
[image: UPDATED]

The result I'm getting
[image: The result I'm getting]

Comment: What isn't getting clipped?

Comment: are you inheriting the class from UITableViewController?? If not than self.clipsToBounds won't clips your tableview cell

Comment: The question was updated, i have added an image. I'm not inheriting from UITbleViewController, and awakfromnib is inside of my custom UITablewViewCell class.

Comment: That doesnt help much, that is the result you want, but what is the result you are getting?

Comment: Yes i tried, but in that case the bottom corners also are getting rounded which is not acceptable.

Comment: If you want this only for the top cell in a section, I think it would be easier to draw manually this 10px height view as a section header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: This may be the issue since clipToBounds is not working on the backgroudView or contentView:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/919408/480415

> I believe that the rounded corners of the Grouped style are actually
>   backgrounds of the table cells. Thus you can't just replace the white
>   part, because it's not solid color with drawn border - it's ImageView
>   acting as backgroundView for the cell (using different graphics
>   depending of the cell row and number of rows in section).

If that is the case than you may have use Core Graphics and customize the cells to your liking. [Heres a good tutorial by Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2033/core-graphics-101-lines-rectangles-and-gradients)

---

A couple things I would try:

First.. just see if this has any effect:

```
self.backgroundView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

and

```
self.contentView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

If not, I would try to round the headerView

```
self.headerView.layer.cornerRadius = 5; //try different ints here
```

Comment: self.backgroundView.clipsToBounds = YES; no effect:
self.headerView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;- rounded all corners, but in picture the bottom corners are not rounded

Comment: Try self.contentView.clipsToBounds = YES;

Comment: i did it, also i tried self.headerView.superView.clipsToBounds=YES;
no result.

Comment: Hmm I posted a link in my answer that may be why clipToBounds is not working

Comment: thanks for your help. I'm marking your reply as answer. But i find another solution, I'm just rounding headerview layer as you said  and putting another view to headerview bottom to hide bottom corner.

Comment: Yeah I was going to suggest that but it is not very clean-- I don't see it causing any performance issues but without going hardcore and creating your own 'GroupedTableView' style, its probably the easiest option. I've come to learn Apple does not like you customizing their grouped table views too much

Comment: I hope they will not reject my application ))

Comment: No they would not reject for that-- I just mean they don't make it easy